# Post-hoc inventory/queue size query

Tags: database, excel, ms-access

Say you have a list of events/tasks with time stamps for created, completed.

Examples:

- Customer entering a queue, then being served
- Business process starting and completing
- Order received, order dispatched

Also related fill, take events:

- Pay goes into bank account, pay bills, buy food, go to the movies
- Fuel tanker replenishes gas station, customers purchase fuel
- Store receives stock, customers purchase stock

Now say I have a huge list of this data. I don't know the starting inventory levels because I've come in after the beginning and I can't view the current inventory either.

How can I query this data so I can tell current inventory levels, queue size, etc at any given time? Or even start to plot the size of inventory on a time line?

edit: I'll explain my specific requirements in more detail

Our warehouse management sytem contains historical data for each task that occurs. It doesn't capture the state of a pick bin as the event happens, only how much was picked or how much was replenished. We also have cycle count tasks which does show how much stock is in the pick bin. I am trying to find a way of tying these three processes together, replenishment, picking, cycle counts, so I can plot on a time line:

- how many tasks are currently waiting
- current stock levels

At the moment with the data, I have only figured out how to plot how many tasks were created or completed in period of time, or how much was picked, based off the time stamps for the task.

Now the reason I would like this data is to track performance, under/over allocation of staff and indentifying config issues that could be causing performance issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now say I have a huge list of this data. I don't know the starting inventory levels because I've come in after the beginning and I can't view the current inventory either.
>
> How can I query this data so I can tell current inventory levels, queue size, etc at any given time?

The short answer is: "You can't."

If all you have are the deposits/withdrawals without an opening balance or a closing balance then there is no way to track the **actual** current balance because you have no reference point from which to start. You *could* track the **relative** balance (or inventory level, or whatever) by **assuming** a starting balance of 0, or 100, or 1000, or any value you like.

As for plotting the data, Excel is the logical place to start for a task like that.